# Two columns end with .x and .y after merged in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-analysis, data-wrangling, exploratory-data-analysis

I merged two dataframe in R, both have id and date columns. I decide to merge by id, after merging there are two date columns, one is date.x and the other is date.y. But I only need one date column

I have searched online for solutions but find none.

Comment: Hello Yomson, please share the code you used and a sample of data, so you question can be reproduced to give you an answer.

Comment: That is because the `date` column is present in both dataframes, and when merging you need a way to differentiate them, so the first one gets the suffix `.x` and the second one `.y`. I guess you can just drop one and change the name of the remaining column to `date` ? Or before merging, drop the `date` column from one of the dataframes.

Comment: If the date column data necessarily match, another solution would be to join by both id and date.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: A reproducible example of your problem would be very nice, just like the others stated already. Nevertheless, I think you, should explore the mutating joins of 'dplyr'. As cucurbit wrote, with these functions you can define a suffix for duplicate columns after merging or even drop them: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate-joins.html

Comment: The dataframe is like this:  

**data1**  
Id                         
date                       
first_test                 
second_test     
exam_score

**data2**
Id  
date  
grade  
graduate_school   

```{r}
new_data <-merge(data1,data2, by = "Id",all=TRUE) %>% drop_na()
```
when I run the code it gave me new_data with these columns

**new_data**
Id                         
*date.x*                     
first_test                 
second_test                
exam_score
*date.y*
grade  
graduate_school